# How to calculate opacity of smoggy air (astrophysics)?

Tags: astrophysics

The question asks what the opacity of smog in the air is if you can just barely see a city that is 60km away. There is no other information.

My thinking is that "just barely visible" means I have to use an apparent magnitude of 6 in any calculations. The formulas I have are:

m-M = 5logr - 5 (distance modulus through a vacuum)

m-M = 5logr -5 + A (distance modulus through dust where A is the extinction)

A ~= t where t is optical depth

a = rt where a is opacity and r is distance?

I can't seem to put these equations together, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can start by looking up the standards for visibility; they are referenced in this article: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility>

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).